# Extracting Numbers from Formatted Strings with Unusual Delimiters in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing

How can I get the numbers in a formatted string like the following in Python? It has a mixed combination of delimiters such as `tab`, `parenthesis`, `cm`, `space`, and `#`.

I used the following code but it does not split the numbers correctly.

```
s = "1.0000e+036 (1.2365e-004,6.3265e+003cm) (2.3659e-002, 2.3659e-002#)"
parts = re.split('\s|(?<!\d)[,.](?!\d)', s)
print(parts)
['1.0000e+036', '(1.2365e-004,6.3265e+003cm)', '(2.3659e-002,', '2.3659e-002#)']
```

I am trying to extract:

```
[1.0000e+036, 1.2365e-004, 6.3265e+003, 2.3659e-002, 2.3659e-002]
```

Could someone kindly help?

**Update:**

I tried the regular expression as following, which fails to split the positive exponential numbers

```
s = "1.0000e+036 (1.2365e-004,6.3265e+003cm) (2.3659e-002, 2.3659e-002#)"
match_number = re.compile('-?\ *[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(?:[Ee]\ *-?\ *[0-9]+)?')
final_list = [float(x) for x in re.findall(match_number, s)]
print(final_list)
[1.0, 36.0, 0.00012365, 6.3265, 3.0, 0.023659, 0.023659]
```

As can be seen, the first number is `1e36` which was parsed as two numbers `1.0` and `36.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to treat those items as delimiters.  Rather, all you appear to need is a regex to extract all the floats in the line (including exponential / engineering notation), and simply ignore the remaining characters.  Comprehensive numerical expressions are readily available on line with a simple search.

Comment: Thank you. regex helped a lot. However, it was not able to extract the number with a positive exponent. Please see the updated question.

Comment: You need the "greedy" version, which will take the *longest* qualifying string.